# Why is my code not reading if pay= false? It just skips that and prints the cost rather than final cost when pay = false

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
public class Gas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double price = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        Boolean pay;
        double finalCost;
        double cost = (price*amount);
        if(pay = false){
            finalCost = cost;
            cost = cost*0.1;
            finalCost = cost + finalCost;
            System.out.println(finalCost);
        }
        if(pay = true){
            System.out.println(cost);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically my code determines cost of gas, so if pay = false then a credit card is being used and their is an extra charge of 10%. Whereas if pay = true, then cash is being used. Whenever I put in false, it prints out the value as if it was true. How could I fix this?

Comment: In Java, `=` is for assigning a value to a variable, not for comparing two values.  You can just write `if (! pay)` to check if it's false, and `if(pay)` to check if it's true.

Comment: you need to initialise what pay is equal to, currently you define that 'pay' is a Boolean, but you don't actually set it to true or false before entering your if statements

Comment: yeah, how is your pay variable set?  Looks like it's undefined at the moment.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem To further this a little bit, `==` is used for comparing two values. So if you wanted to keep the same syntax, you would use `if(pay == true)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **==**, or in this case that you have a boolean, just do this:

```
if(pay) {
   ...
}
```

And you haven't initialized **pay**, for instance:

```
Boolean pay = false;
```